# Ansible 2.7 how to loop though a list of users and run a set of tasks

Tags: ansible

I have a set of tasks that I would like repeated with a loop with a list of users using Ansible 2.7 loop. My simple playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    username: "{{ item }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "running as {{ username }}"

    - name: echo the username
      command: "/bin/echo echoing {{ username }}"

      loop:
        - joe
        - fred
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I see that it cannot possible to combined ansible blocks with loop so maybe this will be helpful for you https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/6zt66i/looping_over_a_block_of_tasks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to execute a group of sub-tasks, especially under a looping construct, you'll want `include_tasks:`, like so:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: the-other-tasks.yml
    with_items:
    - alpha
    - beta
```

(I'm using `with_items:` because it's the most succinct in this example, but AFAIK that's just syntatic sugar for `loop:` and its `loop_var:` friends and so it should work as expected)